# JavaPNS alternatives?

Tags: java, iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

The company I work for has an issue with using LGPL software, are there any viable alternatives to JavaPNS or is it the clear leader for Java and APN?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining the JavAPNS library take time and effort. If you or your company isn't willing to help support/improve it, yet expects many man-hours to have been spent in making it stable then feel free to go elsewhere.

Have you looked at:

https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns

It says: Licensed under the New 3-Clause BSD License.

Comment: I up-voted this because it does provide an answer that was valuable to me.  However, it is unnecessarily preachy.  No need to say "feel free to go elsewhere" when his question was, "where else can I go?"